# Undo iptables modification

Tags: linux, iptables

I ran the following `iptables` commands to create a blacklist rule but used the wrong port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j SSH_WHITELIST
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j ULOG --ulog-prefix SSH_brute_force
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```

How can I undo the above and then redo it for a different port?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use iptables -D ... to delete the entries.

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j SSH_WHITELIST
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j ULOG --ulog-prefix SSH_brute_force
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```

Answer (score 8):

Run the same commands with `-D` instead of `-A`.

Alternatively, if you want to completely reset the iptables, flush everything with `iptables -F`.

Comment: i ran iptables -F and now my server is inaccessible. iptables -F seems to be a bit different from ufw reset.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you didn't run the `iptables save` command, all you should have to do is restart or reload the iptables service. Or, you can do what Bonsi Scott said and delete the rules -- with a caveat. First run:

```
#iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers
```

to get the rule number, then all you would have to do is delete the rule by number with:

```
#iptables -D INPUT <rule number>
```